# How to block a link and return 404 page?

Tags: wordpress, nginx

How to block in nginx a link archive pages Wordpress - http://site.ru/2014/03/, http://site.ru/2014/04/ and so on. Block page archives all years, and month. And return 404 page? Sorry for my english.

Comment: Might I ask why you would want to do this? What's the point?

Comment: reference weight decreases

Answer (score 0):

You could insert a 301 redirect in your .htaccess file for your archive pages.  Something like:

```
Redirect 301 /2014/03 http://www.example.com/404
Redirect 301 /2014/04 http://www.example.com/404
```

Or...

Try adding the following to the beginning of your Archives theme file.  Replace 'Page Title' with the title of your 404 page:

```
<?php
if(is_date()) {
$pagelink=get_page_link (get_page_by_title( 'Page Title' ));
header("Location: $pagelink",TRUE,301);
}
?>
```

Comment: nginx not support .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to .htaccess, you could take advantage of the inbuilt WordPress hooks `template_redirect` and `wp_redirect`. The following will go in your theme's functions.php file.

```
function custom_redirect_archives() {
    if ( is_date() ) {
        wp_redirect( $link, 301 );
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'custom_redirect_archives' );
```

**Note:** Change `$link` to the page you want the user to be redirected to.

*References:*

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect